# What is the correct encoding for a video to play it with javafx

Tags: java, audio, javafx, video, codec

I do have some issues with the encoding of my video which has a video and an audio stream, so that it can be displayed with the JavaFX MediaPlayer.

I am using OpenJDK 11 and OpenJFX 11. For JavaFX 8 I found [this documentation on the Oracles page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm#JFXMD101):

> Supported Media Codecs
>
> The formats currently supported are the following:
>   -    Audio: MP3; AIFF containing uncompressed PCM; WAV containing uncompressed PCM; MPEG-4 multimedia container with Advanced Audio Coding (AAC) audio
>   -    Video: FLV containing VP6 video and MP3 audio; MPEG-4 multimedia container with H.264/AVC (Advanced Video Coding) video compression

And further down the supported features:

> - FLV container with MP3 and VP6
> - MP3 audio
> - MPEG-4 container with either AAC, H.264, or both

For OpenJFX I have not found any corresponding documentation, therefore I assume that this is still true in OpenJFX 11.

However I have run into issues where my video does not play on all environments (Windows, Linux and Mac):

- Encoding with H.264 and MP3 worked on Linux, but not on Windows, did not even test it on Mac (See also [JavaFX media player does not play video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53929287/javafx-media-player-does-not-play-video))
- Encoding with H.264 and AAC worked on Linux and on Windows, but not on Mac
  To encode I used this command under Linux:

  ffmpeg -i fire.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict -2 output.mp4

What combination of video codec and audio codec works on all three operating systems? Preferably in the form of the ffmpeg conversion command, as there are for example different options to encode the video stream with H.264.

Comment: Note that supported types/encodings/containers/etc are documented by the [`javafx.scene.media`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: @Slaw: That documentation confirms my assumptions, so the encoding combination of H.264 with either AAC or MP3 in a MP4 container should work.